# Prolog: insert in a tuple

Tags: list, prolog

In a 3-tuple, how can I put the character '#' as the middle term of the tuple.

predicate: duplicate(L1,L2).

?­ duplicate([30,40,50],X).

X = [ (30, #, 30), (40, #, 40), (50, #, 50)].

?­ duplicate([80],X).

X = [ (80, #, 80)].

?­ duplicate([],X).

X = [].

Tks

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
duplicate([],[]).                                            
duplicate([H|T], [(H, '#', H)|R]) :- duplicate(T,R).
```

Isn't prolog wonderful?

Comment: Even better: `hash_triple(X, (X, '#', X)).` then `maplist(hash_triple, Lst, Out)`.

Comment: Using [`library(lambda)`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/ISO-Hiord) (preinstalled in YAP): `maplist(\H^(H, '#', H)^true, Lst, Out)`